# Olympic Problem - Painting points red on a circumference

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

> There are $33$ points on the circumference of a circle that divide it into $33$ equal parts. These points are numbered consecutively and clockwise as $0, 1, 2, 3, \dotsc, 32$. Some of these points are painted red with the property that no two pairs of red points are the same distance apart (we define the distance of two points on the circumference as the minimum arc length between these points). What is the highest number of points that can be painted red?

Comment: I think I found the upper bound, but I'm having trouble proving that it is not possible with $8$ points.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the "obvious" upper bound was $6$, since with $7$ points, there are $7\cdot 6$ differences, which is greater than $32$. Did you find an example with $7$?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see it like that! Checking again, I have a lot of examples with $5$ but can't get higher than that.
Also, I think with 6 points you have 21 differences.

Comment: But you're right since you only have $16$ possible distances.

Comment: I do not quite follow! I would say paint 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, which is $7$ points. The distances are $1+2+3+4+5+6+12=33$. More than this will be impossible, since their distance sum would be lower bounded by $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8=36$ which is greater than the available $33$.

Comment: Effectively, the highest number of points is 5 because let's say we paint one point red and then we paint another such that their distance is $x$. Then we paint another one such that the distance between the second point and this new one is $y$. This way we won't be able to use $x+y$ or $33-(x+y)$ (I'm going to assume the distance between two consecutive points is 1) Repeat this with another point and distance $z$, we won't be able to use $15=5*3$ distances (which is the number of distances with $6$ points)

Comment: If you paint 0, 1, 3 and 6, the distance between 0 and 3 is the same distance between 3 and 6.

Comment: @Rigo: Ah, ok. So it is not enough for consecutive points to have different distances?

Comment: "No two pairs" doesn't say consecutive, so, unless the OP left something out, it is not a condition. @String

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, I realize that now. I simply misread it. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear why we can't get $15$ distinct distances, @Rigo. It might be hard, but there are $16$ possible non-zero values for the distances.